# Htaccess redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

In php site's .htaccess file

there is a section of code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.test\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

What it exactly means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect test.com requests to https://www.test.com and preserve any URI params.

Answer (score 1):

It means, that if you request `http://test.com/...` (note NO `www` here) - you will be redirected to correspondent `http://www.test.com/...`